# HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found in Azure with asp.net MVC and WebAPI core 2.1

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-2.1

Hi All I am getting below error, There is no publishing error. and also checked by deploying a MVC core 2.1 application which is generated by VS 2017 and the application also contains the font file. In that it does not produce any error and runs fine. But the project its giving below exception and the details are...

```html
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Most likely causes:
It is possible that a handler mapping is missing. By default, the static file handler processes all content.
The feature you are trying to use may not be installed.
The appropriate MIME map is not enabled for the Web site or application. (Warning: Do not create a MIME map for content that users should not download, such as .ASPX pages or .config files.)
If ASP.NET is not installed.

Things you can try:
In system.webServer/handlers:
Ensure that the expected handler for the current page is mapped.
Pay extra attention to preconditions (for example, runtimeVersion, pipelineMode, bitness) and compare them to the settings for your application pool.
Pay extra attention to typographical errors in the expected handler line.
Please verify that the feature you are trying to use is installed.
Verify that the MIME map is enabled or add the MIME map for the Web site using the command-line tool appcmd.exe.
To set a MIME type, use the following syntax: %SystemRoot%\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config /section:staticContent /+[fileExtension='string',mimeType='string']
The variable fileExtension string is the file name extension and the variable mimeType string is the file type description.
For example, to add a MIME map for a file which has the extension ".xyz": appcmd set config /section:staticContent /+[fileExtension='.xyz',mimeType='text/plain']
Warning: Ensure that this MIME mapping is needed for your Web server before adding it to the list. Configuration files such as .CONFIG or dynamic scripting pages such as .ASP or .ASPX, should not be downloaded directly and should always be processed through a handler. Other files such as database files or those used to store configuration, like .XML or .MDF, are sometimes used to store configuration information. Determine if clients can download these file types before enabling them.
Install ASP.NET.
Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click here.

Detailed Error Information:
Module    StaticFileModule
Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    StaticFile
Error Code    0x80070032
Requested URL    https://~1GpsLearning:80/Content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
Physical Path    D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\79.20129.3767\Content\fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
Logon Method    Anonymous
Logon User    Anonymous
```

Comment: It seems that you haven't published your files properly. I follow this article http://dotnet4hosting.asphostportal.com/post/How-to-Publish-ASPNET-Core-2.aspx and it is working fine

Comment: Hi @Mark, have tried to download the said file from the link but it only have for 2.0, As I am working on 2.1 and VS 2017.  Can you please send link mint for 2.1 core on Azure.

Comment: Try this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the issue of up-gradation from 2.0 to 2.1, SO I created a fresh application in 2.1 core and just implemented my other code as it is and every thing worked fine and is running on azure very smoothly.